# Run command on telnet connected switch using python

Tags: python, telnet

I'm tring to send simple command to hp switch using telnet. No errors are on python side, only strange things in debugging respone.

```
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.5.101"
user = "admin"
password = "password"


telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
telnet.set_debuglevel(9)
telnet.read_until(b"login: ")

telnet.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
telnet.read_until(b"Password: ")
telnet.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

tn.write(b"system-view\n")
```

Response:

```
recv  b'\r\n\r\nUsername:'
recv  b'\r\n% Username:  timeout expire!'
send  b'admin\n'
recv  b'\r\nUsername:admin\r\nPassword:'
recv b'\r\n% Username:    timeout expired!'
recv b''
send b'password\n'
send b'system-view\n'
ConnectionAbortedError:   Windows 10053
```

Can't find out problem it cannot send username and password, or problem in executing command on switch?

Comment: Note that the proper "newline" for Telnet is `"\r\n"`, as shown in the responses you get.

Comment: Your code expects a `login: ` prompt while the remote host waits for input on a `Username:` prompt. Also, the host's prompts don't seem to have trailing whitespace characters while your expect patterns do.

Comment: yes, problem was in whitespaces after login/password and command should be encoded too, thx

Answer (score 0):

From: https://supportline.microfocus.com/kbdocs/KBdo11680.HTM

> 10053 is a socket-based error code that is returned when a Winsock
>   function encounters an error during the socket transmission process.
>   Because QALoad transmits some of its middleware requests via sockets,
>   this type of error can affect a QALoad test.
>
> You can check the following items (some might not apply to your
>   situation) when a 10053 error occurs:
>
> - Check the network -- you might need to use sniffer trace software for    more information about the packets.
> - Check the request being sent in    the script to see if it is valid.
> - Check the number of users that    encountered the error and determine whether they always encounter the    same error on the same
>     request.